# Error creating spring boot bean - "The blank final field em may not have been initialized"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I am a newbie for the spring boot framework. I have successfully done crud operation. After that I have decided that to do Advanced search concepts. Please see the code below, which I used.

```
package com.lean.repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.lean.entity.Merchant;

    public interface MerchantDao extends JpaRepository<Merchant, Long> {
        EntityManager em;

        public List<Merchant> findAllByNameIn(Set<String> name);

        public default List<Merchant> findMerchantList(String name, String email) {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Merchant> cq = cb.createQuery(Merchant.class);

            Root<Merchant> book = cq.from(Merchant.class);
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if (name != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(book.get("name"), name));
            }
            if (email != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(book.get("email"), email));
            }
            cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

            return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        };

    }
```

Here, I am getting the below error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'merchantDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The blank final field em may not have been initialized
```

When I am trying to get the"EntityManager em" entity object, I will get the above error.

Please help someone to fix the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Also check for below dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This above answer is not working. Already I have tried this. Do we need create any beans for this?

Comment: Can you check for the dependencies I have mentioned. Also, can you show datasource properties.

Comment: Yes. I have installed the provided dependencies which are above. But still, the same errors coming

Comment: Do you mean dao file?

Comment: application.properties or yaml file where you have database properties.